# Multi threading delegate issue, Method name expected?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, delegates, threadpool

Right, this is my first venture into multi threading so could be something incredibly simple I'm missing but here goes...

I'm using thread pool to kick off a bunch of short running processes  at the same time, each will be passed a URL to process/scrape for fb-tweets-google-plusones and return a result to my `ReportProgress` method by invoking the delegate `ThreadDone` but when passing in the processed object once the thread's done processing, i keep getting the error `Method name expected` but I'm passing in the method `ReportProgress`? I'm willing to bet (hoping) it's something incredibly simple that someone more experienced can spot right away. Here is what i have so far:

Delegate definition:

```
public delegate void ThreadDone(object sender, ScrapeResult scrapedResult);
```

DoWork:

```
public void DoWork(object sender)
{
      while (true)
      {
          //lock the thread to prevent other threads from processing same job
          lock (_threadLock)
          {   
              string url = (string)sender;
              result.URL = url;

              if (chkFb.Checked)
              {
                  result.Shares = grabber.GetFacebookShares(url);
              }
              if (chkTwitt.Checked)
              {
                  result.Tweets = grabber.GetTweetCount(url);
              }
              if (chkPlusOne.Checked)
              {
                  result.PlusOnes = grabber.GetPlusOnes(url);
              }

              this.Invoke(new ThreadDone(ReportProgress(sender, result))); //ERROR is on this line
           }
           Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
}
```

ReportProgress:

```
private void ReportProgress(object sender, ScrapeResult scrapedResult)//<-- might not need?
{
     progressBar.Value++;
     ScrapeResult result = (ScrapeResult)sender;//ScrapedResult result = scrapedResult;
     outputGrid.Rows.Add(result.URL, result.Shares, result.Tweets, result.PlusOnes);
     outputGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
     outputGrid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.Invoke(new ThreadDone(ReportProgress(sender, result)));
```

To:

```
this.Invoke(new ThreadDone(ReportProgress), sender, result);
```

The first parameter of `Invoke()` is the delegate, to build a delegate you do not need to give its parameters but only the method to call (that's why compiler says "method name expected") With `new ThreadDone(ReportProgress)` you create the new delegate and with 2nd and 3rd parameter of `Invoke()` you specify the parameters that will be passed to your delegate.

Comment: Knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks @Adriano.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously consider using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Much cleaner to handle the finish of a task.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions! I have a previous version of the app that uses a Background worker to process the URL's one by one but a friend recommended ThreadPool as a better alternative. When benefits over TP does it offer?

Comment: If you start and handle thread manually its quite fiddly to start another thread/action when a current finishes. Using the TPL you can chain tasks together, you can start an action (or new task) once a task finished, etc.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll look into it right now. What are your thoughts on using `Thread` over `ThreadPool`?

Comment: ThreadPool over Thread. If possible, do not create Threads yourself, they are expensive. The ThreadPool creates its own thread, and reuses them when it can.

Comment: TPL looks to be the better solution. Pretty cool how you can chain tasks one after the other. Cancelling/Finishing tasks with it would be much better than my current implementation using `Interlocked.Decrement` to -1 from a work counter lol